# delete row with specific parameter of csv with php

Tags: php, csv

I tried a lot of things, but none of them seems to work properly...
This is the csv file:
[image: file csv]

and this is my code:

```
                $file_handle = fopen('file.csv', 'r+'); 
                $positionID = 47901392; 
                while ($data = fgetcsv ($file_handle, 1000, ";")) {
            
                    $prod_id  =  $data[0];

                    if($prod_id ==$positionID){
                        echo "prod_id $prod_id ";
                        echo "I have to delete row";
                    }
                    
                    
                }
```

I have to delete row with specific $positionID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open another file to hold the new file with the lines deleted. Then have your loop write everything that isn't deleted to that file.

```
$file_handle = fopen('file.csv', 'r');
$out_handle = fopen('new_file.csv', 'w');
$positionID = 47901392; 
while ($data = fgetcsv ($file_handle, 1000, ";")) {
    $prod_id  =  $data[0];

    if($prod_id ==$positionID){
        echo "prod_id $prod_id ";
        echo "I have to delete row";
    } else {
        fputcsv($out_handle, $data);
    }
}
fclose($file_handle);
fclose($out_handle);
rename('new_file.csv', 'file.csv');
```